# Angular removing Validators.min from form control validation

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have a form with 2 fields:

- includeValidation, a select dropdown (2 option): with validation, without validation
- amount, an input number field

depending on the first dropdown I have validators on the 2nd field: Validators.required, Validators.min(0.1).

Im trying to use clearValidators() to remove the validation but it only removes the required but not the min(0.1)

How do I remove the min(0.1) when includeValidation == "without validation"

[code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdngbr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**formtest.ts**

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
    this.initValueChanges();
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      includeValidation: [''],
      amount: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.1)]]
    });
  }

  initValueChanges() {
    this.addForm.get('includeValidation').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === 'with validation') {
        this.addForm.get('amount').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.min(0.1)]);
        
      } else if(value === 'without validation') {
        this.addForm.get('amount').setValue(0);
        this.addForm.get('amount').clearValidators();
      }
    });
  }
  
    previewSaveButton() {
        this.addForm.get('amount').updateValueAndValidity();

        if(this.addForm.valid) {
        
        }
    }
```

**formtest.html**

```html
  <form novalidate role="form" name="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>General</h5>
        <div class="form-group"><label>include Validation</label>
          <select name="includeValidation" class="form-control" formControlName="includeValidation">
            <option></option>
            <option value="with validation">with validation</option>
            <option value="without validation">without validation</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"><label>amount</label>
          <input name="amount" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="amount">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button type="submit" (click)="previewSaveButton()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly call `updateValueAndValidity()` whenever you add or remove a validator at runtime.

From [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearvalidators):

> When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect.

Try this:

```ts
initValueChanges() {
    this.addForm.get('includeValidation').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if(value === 'with validation') {
        this.addForm.get('amount').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.min(0.1)]);
        
      } else if(value === 'without validation') {
        this.addForm.get('amount').setValue(0);
        this.addForm.get('amount').clearValidators();
      }
      this.addForm.get('amount').updateValueAndValidity();  // <-- added this line
    });
  }
```

Comment: so the reason i left updateValueAndValidity till the previewSaveButton is because as soon as includeValidation is changed. it marks the amount as invalid straight away.
though, amount should only mark as invalid on when previewSaveButton is called

Comment: _Im trying to use clearValidators() to remove the validation but it only removes the required but not the min(0.1)_ Why do you feel this way? clearValidators() does remove all the validators, but for it to take effect `updateValueAndValidity` needs to be called. You are manually setting value as 0 before clearing, so it satisfies the `required` validator. If you set value as 1, then it will satisfy both the validators.

Comment: @helloworld you can call `updateValueAndValidity` within `else-if` block and not outside it as shown in the answer, but for the validity to be updated the method needs to be called.

Comment: i dont like the suggestion to put updateValueAndValidity within else-if as it's also needed for the setValidators

Comment: it doesnt remove the validation when updateValueAndValidity is in previewSaveButton. it removes the required, but min 0.1 actually remains and marks the form invalid. Does updateValueAndValidity need to stay within the subscribe?

Comment: `clearValidators()` does remove all the validators, but for it to reflect in form control validity, updateValueAndValidity needs to be called.  `updateValueAndValidity` within previewSaveButton should update the validity and the `amount` form control should be valid if `includeValidation` is set to 'without validation'. If this is not the case, then can you please minimal reproducible example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: it magically works now, i dont know what changed. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdngbr?file=src/app/app.component.ts